# some strange sums ramanujan type

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

i found sum as
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{k x} \left(-\frac{1}{y}\right)^k}{p-e^{k x}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{-1+\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{2 i n \pi -\log \left(-\frac{1}{y}\right)}{x};\frac{2 i \pi  n+x-\log \left(-\frac{1}{y}\right)}{x};p\right)}{-\log \left(-\frac{1}{y}\right)+2 i \pi  n}-\frac{-1+\, _2F_1\left(1,-\frac{2 i \pi  n+\log \left(-\frac{1}{y}\right)}{x};\frac{-2 i \pi  n+x-\log \left(-\frac{1}{y}\right)}{x};p\right)}{\log \left(-\frac{1}{y}\right)+2 i \pi  n}\right)+\frac{p^{\frac{\log \left(-\frac{1}{y}\right)}{x}} B_p\left(-\frac{\log \left(-\frac{1}{y}\right)}{x},0\right)}{x}+\frac{1}{2-2 p}+\frac{1}{\log \left(-\frac{1}{y}\right)}$$ numerically seem to work but it is possible to simplify the hypergeometric function

Comment: what does $B_p(...,0)$ mean?

Comment: it is Beta function